# How do I add Android & iOS device images on the landing page

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I saw Android and iOS device image on Instagram website landing page. I would like to add it to my website.

Is there any service available which can generate it automatically by just giving the image ?

I have added uploaded a sample from instagram here.

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL7Ue.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://mockuphone.com/ to generate Screenshots for both Android and iOS.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother :) I don't understand why I got -2 down vote. :/

Comment: This question doesn't belong here. This sub-forum is for programming related questions. That's why people down voted your question. You can check all forums here: https://stackexchange.com/sites#